# Redirecting stderr, stdout and stdin to pipe is blocking the process from running

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I have written a simple [application](https://ideone.com/vDWAvR) which has two threads. First thread is printing to stdout and second thread is reading from stdin.

I have redirected stdin, stdout and stdin of the process to 3 different pipes as below.

```
mkfifo pipe_in && mkifo pipe_out && mkfifo pipe_err

./a.out < pipe_in 2> pipe_err 1> pipe_out &
```

Problem is that I this application (./a.out) is blocked from running until I do below:

```
cat < pipe_out &
cat < pipe_err &
cat > pipe_in
```

Why is this application blocked? Is it because no body from other side has opened the [pipe](http://www.cs.kent.edu/~ruttan/sysprog/lectures/shmem/pipes)?

What is the workaround for the problem where I want to run my application without it being blocked completely. I want only the thread which is waiting for user input to get blocked and other thread to continue execution.

This application is started at bootup. So, this application should be run without getting blocked for user input. User can use anytime "cat > pipe_in" to start providing input to get some details about this application.

Comment: re "workaround" - er, why *would* the rest of your application be blocked? Threads are separate things ...

Comment: But if you're writing a daemon, it should open a socket on its own to provide info rather than using stdio at all - or use signals for a very rough approach.

Comment: @o11c: this is kind of deamon but it has interfaces to get user input for getting information about this application. Kind of test mode to check certain things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Redirection is done by the shell, before starting the application program. Thus `a.out` does not start, and cannot create any threads that do anything, until the opens of the pipes complete, and the opens of the pipe write sides (for 1 and 2) do not complete until the read sides are opened. (The open of a read side for 0 does complete immediately.)